# Create an admin menu in Opencart 4

Tags: opencart, opencart-module

In Opencart4 I am creating a new module. Installed the module and working fine from accessing `Admin-> extensions -> modules -> module name -> (then edit)`.

Now I would like to add a new menu item under the "Catalogue" menu in the admin part.

I have done the following

In module's controller I added

```
$this->load->model('setting/event');
$this->model_setting_event->deleteEventByCode('MY_EVENT');
$this->model_setting_event->addEvent('MY_EVENT', "",'admin/view/common/column_left/before', 'extension/testimonials/module/testimonials/ADDTOADMINMENU');
```

`ADDTOADMINMENU` function in the module's controller looks like

```
public function ADDTOADMINMENU(&$route, &$data){

        /**
        * Check if current logged in user has permission to access that link
        * Replace "extension/module/MY_EXTENSION" with your target path
        * This check can very well be ignored/deleted...
        **/
    echo "Here";
    exit;
        if ($this->user->hasPermission('access', 'extension/testimonials/module/testimonials')) {
            $my_menu_entry = array(
                'id'       => 'menu-MY_EXTENSION',
                'icon'     => 'fa-check',
                'name'     => 'My menu entry',
                'href'     => $this->url->link('extension/testimonials/module/testimonials', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'], true),
                'children' => array()
            );
    
            $target_menu_id      = 'menu-catalog';
            $target_submenu_href = $this->url->link('catalog/product', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'], true);
    
            $new_menu = array();
    
            foreach( $data['menus'] as &$menu ) {
    
                if( $menu['id'] == $target_menu_id ) {
    
                    $new_submenu = array();
    
                    foreach( $menu['children'] as $submenu ) {
                        if( $submenu['href'] == $target_submenu_href ) {
                            $new_submenu[] = $my_menu_entry;
                            $new_submenu[] = $submenu;
                        } else {
                            $new_submenu[] = $submenu;
                        }
                    }
                    $menu['children'] = $new_submenu;
                    $new_menu[] = $menu;
                } else {
                    $new_menu[] = $menu;
                }
            }
    
            $data['menus'] = $new_menu;
        }
    }
```

But not even entering in this function. Is the correct way I am following ?

Please guide.

Comment: Have you checked your new event `'MY_EVENT'` in OC events list?

Comment: Yes. In event table ```code - my_event, trigger - admin/view/common/column_left/before, action - testimonials/events/addSubmenu, status - 1, sort_order - 1```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$this->model_setting_event->addEvent('MY_EVENT', "",'admin/view/common/column_left/before', 'extension/testimonials/module/testimonials/ADDTOADMINMENU');
```

replace with:

```
$this->model_setting_event->addEvent('MY_EVENT', "",'admin/view/common/column_left/before', 'extension/testimonials/module/testimonials|ADDTOADMINMENU');
```

I have not checked, but OC have changed they framework a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

Replace

```
$this->model_setting_event->addEvent('MY_EVENT', "",'admin/view/common/column_left/before', 'extension/testimonials/module/testimonials/ADDTOADMINMENU');
```

With

```
    $dataEvent = [
            'code' => 'MY_EVENT',
            'description' => '',
            'trigger' => 'admin/view/common/column_left/before',
            'action' => 'extension/testimonials/module/testimonials|ADDTOADMINMENU',
            'status' => true,
            'sort_order' => 0,
        ];

    if (version_compare(VERSION, '4.0.1.0', '>=')) {
        $this->model_setting_event->addEvent($dataEvent);
    } elseif (version_compare(VERSION, '4.0.0.0', '>=')) { 
        $this->model_setting_event->addEvent($dataEvent['code'], $dataEvent['description'], $dataEvent['trigger'], $dataEvent['action'], $dataEvent['status'], $dataEvent['sort_order']);
    }else {

        /* compatibility Opencart 3 */
        $dataEvent['trigger']=str_replace("|","/",$dataEvent['trigger']);

        $this->model_setting_event->addEvent($dataEvent['code'], $dataEvent['trigger'], $dataEvent['action'], $dataEvent['status'], $dataEvent['sort_order']);
    }
```

Now you can use your code to update also Admin menu on Opencart 3